# How to connect current edge using pywinauto and input url?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to control current MS Edge and visit a url, say, `https://edition.cnn.com/`.

Here is the code:

```
import pywinauto
import psutil

ids = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'MicrosoftEdge' in p.info['name']]

app = pywinauto.Application().connect(process=ids[0]['pid'])
```

Is the above correct?

How to input the url?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could quickly find is using `Desktop` object:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

d = Desktop(backend='uia')
main_window = d.window(title_re='.*- Microsoft Edge', control_type="Window")
#main_window.dump_tree() # print long output with control identifiers

# after some experiments I could find this is correct edit box
address_edit = main_window.child_window(auto_id="addressEditBox", control_type="Edit")
address_edit.set_edit_text('www.google.com')

# could not find another way to start loading the page yet
address_edit.type_keys('{ENTER}')
```

Comment: How about Internet Explorer?

Comment: It has different structure. Need some time to investigate. Do you need any other browser as well? Chrome? Opera?

Comment: I just want ie. Furthermore, how to save the webpage in html using pywinauto?

Comment: There is an old example using `"win32"` backend: [save_from_internet_explorer.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/save_from_internet_explorer.py). I had no chance to write new one yet. Will post it later under another question you've just submitted.